# Chrome devtools: inspect element on item that is visible only if parent has mouse over

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I cannot find an element in the DOM with devtools.

The element appears only if I mouse over it's parent. In the code, on mouse over, with javascript, a lot of classes are added to different elements and only then my child element appears. (There are no hover events, only mouse over with js)

Because there are so many classes, I cannot add them manually. How can I inspect and debug elements in this context? Does Chrome provide any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some code, so we can see the problem.
If you need a certain element to be hovered, you can trigger the event in the console (the mouse should be outside the viewport to not alter the event-state afterwards).

Comment: @zoku It's not hover, it is mouse over with javascript.

Comment: Does the element get removed when you mouse out?

Answer (score 1):

If your event is attached like so:
`document.getElementById('idOfYourElement').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){ console.log('hover'); })`,

you can trigger events programmatically like so:
`document.getElementById('idOfYourElement').dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseover'))`.

If your mouse is outside the viewport it should stay in this state and you can debug in dev-tools.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the [**Chrome devtools**](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) has the tool of handling `hover/mouse over` element see image :

[image]

Comment: thanks, but that is only hover, not mouse over. To me it doesn't work on mouse over javascript event